# storing two classes in a data stucture at once in EIFFEL

Tags: eiffel

I am making a clinic and I need to make a object that stores two medicines at once. The interaction object means MEDICATION_1 is interacting with MEDICATION_2

However the following code is not correct because it does not meet the generic parameter

ERROR: VICG: Actual generic parameter does not conform to constraint.

code:

```
interaction: HASH_TABLE[MEDICATION, MEDICATION]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HASH_TABLE` allows associating objects of one type with objects of another (or the same) type. The first parameter to `HASH_TABLE` is a value and the second one is a key. Therefore one can keep at most one value for the same key. If this suits your needs, the type of keys has to be `HASHABLE`. This type defines a function `hash_code` that computes an integer value for an object. All basic types and `STRING` are `HASHABLE`, so you can rely on the existing implementations to compute `hash_code` for `MEDICATION` objects. For example, if a medication has a unique name, it makes sense to define is as follows:

```
class MEDICATION inherit HASHABLE ... feature ...
   name: STRING
   ...
   hash_code: INTEGER
      do
         Result := name.hash_code
      end
end
```